# Python - print Error text from a log file

Tags: python, logfile

I'm having a log file (example below) tracking errors, warning and info. I would like to create a script in Python which would extract Errors only. I would like to Extract the header with timestamp and lines with error text.

```
>>> Log file (e.g. logfile.log)
=====
2018-10-31 05:20:57.282  WARN
2018-10-31 05:20:57.331  WARN
2018-10-31 05:20:57.367  INFO
2018-10-31 05:20:57.367 ERROR
text
text
text
2018-10-31 05:20:57.367 INFO

>>> Expected results:
2018-10-31 05:20:57.367 ERROR
text
text
text
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: You read the file as lines.  You check each line for the substring "ERROR".  You put those matches into a list.  Each of these is a basic skill that's covered well in tutorials and existing Stack Overflow answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
file_in = open('logfile.log','r') # Read file
for line in file_in: # Loop every line
    if 'ERROR' in line: # Search for ERROR in line
        print(line) # Print line
    elif 'INFO' not in line and 'WARN' not in line: # Remove INFO and WARN lines
        print(line) # Print line
```